# Remove background from top menu and address bar

Tags: css

I'm trying to remove the background layer from the menu and address bar at the top of my page.

Setting `bg-color` to *transparent* shows the default color, which is not the desired effect.

The website in question is here: https://dbijfinance.com.au/.

Comment: Rather than showing us the website link, show us the code.

Comment: on which tag is the bg-color?

Comment: Try changing background:none for .header class

Comment: .bottom-header {
   
  background: none !important; 
    
}
if i put the color in this tag it changes the background color  but nothing works on  background: none

Comment: Fixed grammar. Need's screen shots and code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You can force it by css with !important

```
section#secondary-banner {
background: none!important;
}
```

or find the Javascript that is appending the background.